# Status bar is not hidden in the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios

Despite I have set the value to YES in my .plist file UIStatusBarHidden, it is shown in the storyboard, but not in the simulator or device. How can I remove permanently from views in the storyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to select your initial view controller (either a UINavigationController, a UITabbarController or a simple UIViewController...). Make sure you selected the controller itself and not the root view of the controller.
Then in the inspector on the right panel you can tell if you want to display the status bar.

[image: Interface Builder]

Select none for the initial controller in your storyboard and every controller connected to this one should hide the status bar automatically.
If you have "standalone" controllers on your storyboard you'll have to do the same thing for each of them.